# unlink PHP works when file is in root, not if file is in folder

Tags: php, unlink

So this one is pretty straight forward I want to delete a file on the server using PHP, I have:

```
$myfile = 'theone.png';
unlink($myfile);
```

This code deletes the file, howevere if the path to file is /images/theone.png, it doesn't work, I have tried images\theone.png with no luck.

If I try and connect with FTP I get the error message to say that cURL does not support the unlink function... Any help would be great.

Thanks Guys!

Comment: Did you try `/images/theone.png` or `images/theone.png`?

Comment: Can you show the structure and the exact you (just small part) that's being used?

Comment: surely your image path is incorrect. did you tried `unlink("/images/theone.png");`?

Comment: What does `echo substr(sprintf('%o', fileperms($myfile)), -4);` print?

Comment: URL paths and file locations on the server are very different things. Whereas the leading `/` in `/images/theone.png` means "relative to the current domain" in a URL, in a file path, it means "relative to the very root of the server's file system", which is almost certainly not what you intended (and a directory you may not even have access to). You should specify the actual location on disk of the file to delete, not a relative path.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
$root = realpath($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
$myfile = '$root/images/theone.png';
unlink($myfile);
```

Although to my knowledge, your attempted method should work, unless either I'm missing something, or you haven't included some code here that might be interfering with the unlink.

Comment: I believe what was attempted was `$myfile = '/images/theone.jpg';`, which would look in the root of the server. Your solution fixes this by giving a correct full path for the file to delete.

Comment: Hmm...If I recall correctly, PHP doesn't work the same way as HTML when it comes to putting a / right at the beginning of a file path. I don't remember, since I usually always use the root in conjunction with the path in a similar fashion to my answer.

Comment: I had tried the realpath function with no luck, adding the $root does nothing either....

Comment: Yes, that's the whole problem - it represents the root of the *server*, i.e. the entire operating system, not your particular website. Think `C:\ ` if you're from more of a Windows/DOS background.

Comment: @Rik89: Are you sure you have the correct permissions set in your image directory? That's the only other thing I can think of.

Comment: Correct IMSoP!!!! The root was root to the server not the path where my website resides, print the $root path to screen showed that /delete was missing, once added the script works

Answer (score 2):

`__DIR__` - this magic constant contains current directory, in case that the file is in the same directory as your PHP script you can use:

`unlink(__DIR__ . "/$myfile");`

If the file is for example in one directory above your PHP script you can use:

`unlink(__DIR__ . "/../$myfile");`

If the directory has correct access rights it should work.

Comment: I dont think you undertsand what I need, I can delete the file when it is in the same directory(not that I want to do it that way), I actually want to delete the file in /images/thefile.png

Comment: @Rik89 No, you don't (or I would be *very* surprised if you did). That would be like deleting `C:\images\thefile.png` - that's not a file path you would ever be using. So what you want is to construct a path relative to either a) the running PHP script (this answer) or b) your website's "document root" (Higaran's answer).